# Add variable to the instance of the class

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

I'm trying to add variable to the instance of the class.

In console, I get this error:

```
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'view'
```

And here is the code itself:

```
import sublime_plugin

class TestMe(sublime_plugin.EventListener):

    def __init__(self, view):
        self.view = view
        self.need_update = False

    def setme():
        need_update = True

    def on_activated(self, view):
        setme()
        if need_update == True:
            print("it works")
```

I spend all day trying to figure out different ways to resolve it. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the core of your issue is that you're subclassing `EventListener` and not `ViewEventListener`.

The reason you're seeing this error is that the `__init__` method of the `EventListener` class takes no arguments (with the exception of `self`, which is always present in class methods). When Sublime creates the instance, it doesn't pass in a `view`, and since your `__init__` requires one, you get an error that you're missing a positional parameter.

This is because the events in `EventListener` all pass in the `view` that they apply to (if any), so the class doesn't associate with one specific `view` and thus one is not needed when the listener is created.

In contrast, `ViewEventListener` offers only a subset of the events that `EventListener` does, but its instances apply to a specific view, so its constructor is provided with the view that it applies to. In this case the events themselves don't have a `view` argument because the listener already knows what `view` it is associated with.

A modified version of your code that takes all of this into account would look like this:

```python
import sublime_plugin

class TestMe(sublime_plugin.ViewEventListener):
    def __init__(self, view):
        super().__init__(view)
        self.need_update = False

    def setme(self):
        self.need_update = True

    def on_activated(self):
        self.setme()
        if self.need_update == True:
            print("it works")
```

Here the super class is `ViewEventListener`, for which Sublime will pass a `view` when it is created. This also invokes the super class version of the `__init__` method instead of setting `self.view` to the view passed in, which allows it to do whatever other setup the default class needs to do (in this case none, but better safe than sorry).

Additionally the methods are adjusted a little bit, since in this case every view will have a unique instance of this class created for it:

- `setme` takes a `self` argument so that it knows what instance it is being called for
- `on_activated` does not take a `view` argument because it has access to `self.view` if it needs it
- Calls to `setme` need to be prefixed with `self.` so that python knows what we're trying to do (this also implicitly passes in the `self` argument)
- All accesses for `need_update` are prefixed with `self.` so that each method accesses the version of the variable that is unique to its own instance.